# Wordpress Olam theme - Want to change search function

Tags: wordpress, search

I want to change word-press search logic. So where can I change for customization of wp_query. Below is standard search.

```
$args = array('s'=> get_search_query(),
            'meta_key'  => 'edd_price',
            'order'     => 'ASC',
            'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num meta_value ',
            'post_type' => 'download',
            'posts_per_page'=>$posts_per_page_olam,
            'paged'     => $paged,
            'tax_query' => $taxQuery);
```

Comment: what do you change in search function?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the search on your site, please [hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) on the search query like so :

```
<?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'func_53407889' );
function func_53407889( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search ) {
        // Change here whatever you want using the WP_Query's args
        // $query->set( 'post_type', 'event' );
    }
}
```